# How to use C++ function from Oracle Stored Procedure

Tags: c++, sql, oracle

I have never worked with Oracle, and I normally only Use standard SQL functionality.

I have a C++ Shared Library that I compiled with GCC 4.2.4, and I need to call its functionality from an Oracle Stored Procedure.

Can I use the Shared Library directly as I built it, or do I have to build it with some special tags?

Do I have to create a function or something special in oracle that actually invokes the C++ code?

How do I map the types? Do I have to do some marshaling?

Comment: Yes that can be done.  It's been years since I've worked with Oracle but I think vershov provides the right link.  One thing to be aware of is that if you're planning on calling this routine over and over again it can be very slow overall because of the overheads involved in calling external code.  Sometimes it's necessary though so go right ahead.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you need to use [Oracle External Procedures](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_extern_proc.htm).

Answer (score 1):

Long story short. Oracle will not allow you to access it's address space. C stored procedures work differently than in MySQL and PostgreSQL. You have to:

- create a shared library, link it with Oracle client libs and register it using `CREATE LIBRARY`
- configure the listener. Oracle listener will spawn special process called `extproc` (or `extproc32`). This process will load your shared library and will talk to rest of Oracle via IPC.
- Each time you apply a patch onto Oracle you should also re-link your shared library

Best place for starting is Oracle server installation, containing C OCI samples. There you will find a skeleton of such a shared library and also a `Makefile` which will compile it.

Comment: When you say link it with Oracle, do you mean I have to build it using CC and adding some Oracle Libraries to my code? Also I have a C++ SharedLibrary, not a C one, would it work the same?

Comment: I'm afraid you have create a C wrapper lib for your C++ library and link this lib against OCI lib. You will need this OCI lib also for datatype conversions (int <=> OCINumber, std::string <=> VARVHAR2)